# Quelle est la différence entre «tel», «pareil» et «comme ça»?

Tags: sens

Spécifiquement, dans le contexte qui suit:

1. Je n'ai jamais vu un *tel* gâteau.
2. Je n'ai jamais vu un gâteau *pareil*.
3. Je n'ai jamais vu un gâteau *comme ça*.

À ma connaissance, la différence est la solennité, mais je n'en suis pas sûr, et s'il s'agit de la formalité, quelle forme est la plus soutenue et la moins soutenue?

Comment: Votre classement va de *tel*, soutenu, à *comme ça* familier

Comment: *4. Jamais vu un gâteau ça comme.* :-)

Comment: Un gâteau pareil / (un) pareil gâteau. Un gâteau semblable.

Comment: @jlliagre _ça comme_? vraiment?

Comment: @Frank Eh oui, c'est c'est *asmeuk* :-)

Comment: Je kiffe, je kiffe.

Comment: @Frank C'est kif-kif !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le contexte que vous avez fourni, l'unique différence se trouve dans le degré de formalité et non sur le fond en lui-même.

**"Je n'ai jamais vu un tel gâteau."** Cette phrase est très formelle, et l'utilisation de "tel" ajoute un niveau d'admiration. C'est la forme la plus soutenue parmi les trois.

**"Je n'ai jamais vu un gâteau pareil."** Cette expression est moins formelle que la précédente, mais l'utilisation du mot "pareil" indique une comparaison avec d'autres gâteaux vu auparavant. Cela suggère donc que ce gâteau est différent des autres.

**"Je n'ai jamais vu un gâteau comme ça."** Cette formulation est la moins formelle. Elle est très directe et l'expression "comme ça" indique une comparaison plus générale. Elle convient cependant lors de discussions informelles par exemple.

En résumé, ces trois formulations diffèrent dans le degré de formalité et dans l'expression du caractère unique de ce gâteau.

J'espère que cela vous aidera!

Comment: On peut faire cette distinction sur le degré de formalité, mais je ne crois pas que ce soit nécessairement si tranché. Je suis à peu près d'accord avec cette gradation dans ce cas précis, mais je ne pense pas qu'on puisse en faire une règle systématique.

Comment: _Comme ça_ peut aussi avoir d'autres connotations. Par exemple, _je n'ai jamais vu la situation comme ça_ et _je n'ai jamais vu une situation comme ça_ ne signifient pas la même chose.